# Selenium: Find adjacent elements

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

First off, I hope this question isn't too general in its scope – if so I apologize.

I'm building a web scraper using `Selenium` for `Python 2.7`. Previously, I have used "static" `XPaths` to direct it toward certain elements. I want to implement a solution that can finds elements contextually (relative to other elements).

Let's say we wish to grab the text from the sibling element following the "*Issuer:*" label on this page: http://etfdb.com/etf/ROBO/. In this case the adjacent text is "*Exchange Traded Concepts*".

From what I've gathered, it could be possible to use a number of techniques including relative `XPath`, `CSS` or `DOM`(?).

What would be an advisable way to go about this? Please demonstrate with code if possible.

---

**Current "Static" XPath**, where have identified the XPath with [FirePath](https://github.com/pierretholence/firepath) for Firefox:

```
try:
    xpath_issuer = ".//*[@id='overview']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/span[2]/a"
    find_issuer = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_issuer)
    issuer = re.search(r"(.+)", find_issuer.text).group().encode("utf-8")
    print "Issuer: %s" % issuer
    break
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Comment: why you use more complicated `xpath` selector instead of simple`driver.find_element_by_id('overview')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a reusable function to get the value by key:

- "Exchange Traded Concepts" by "Issuer"
- "ETF" by "Structure" etc

Example working implementation:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def get_value(driver, key):
    key = key + ":"
    try:
        return driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='minimal-list__title' and . = '%s']/following-sibling::span" % key).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "Not Found"
        return None
```

Usage:

```
get_value(driver, "Issuer")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the following xpath

```
//span[@class='minimal-list__title'][text()='Issuer:']//following-sibling::span[@class='minimal-list__value']
```